# get server address from bottle

Tags: python, bottle

Is it possible to get the IP Address of the server programmaticaly in a bottle request?

I need to return a link to a file on the server inside a request and need to know the IP. Bottle will be started on a server with different IPs and all of these IPs will be serve requests.

currently i looks like this:

```
from bottle import *
import json
@get('/file')
def getAFileLink():
    # some logic here for the right filename to return
    # server runs now on e.g. 10.0.0.1 and 10.10.0.1
    # every client should see the IP from the server in the right subnet
    return json.dumps({'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:1337/some/file.abc'})

@route('/some/<filename>')
def getStaticFile(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root="/srv/static/files")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1337)
```

Comment: Who does the request routing?  Are you behind a load balancer?, or are your clients expected to be node (server) aware?  (I'd advise differently depending on the answer.)

Comment: the routing is from the bottle manual: it is used when you want serve static files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your servers aren't behind a load balancer, just use the `Host` HTTP header.

```
@route('/file')
def getAFileLink():
    host = bottle.request.get_header('host')
    return {'url': 'http://{}/some/file.abc'.format(host)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to `bottle.request.url` ([docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.url)).

In case you need only scheme and hostname, use [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to get it.

Comment: Bottle also offers [urlparts](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.urlparts). I think this is the best solution

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
from bottle import request 
urlparts = request.urlparts
print urlparts.scheme
print urlparts.netloc
```

[docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.urlparts)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you running your server on the same ip as the link that you return?

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```